# How to sanitarily measure vacuum in milk?

Tags: pressure, sensors, vacuum

I would like to measure the vacuum inside of a tube which will contain air and milk. A vacuum pump attached to the tube will maintain a vacuum of around 15 inHg.

Are there inexpensive sensors I can use that will work in a milk environment and can be cleaned easily? I have never personally used an electronic pressure transducer and I worry that the milk will get into the inner workings of the transducer and either (a) ruin the transducer or (b) be inaccessible for easy cleaning.

I have found many inexpensive transducers on NXP.com, for example this one:
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPXAZ4115A.pdf

My concern with the sensors above is that the ported variants will be too difficult to clean and the non-ported variants look like they might have a small hole on the top of the sensor in which milk could get into (hard to tell from the line drawings if that is an open hole or a closed membrane).

Comment: I think you will need to separate the sensor from the milk/air mixture using a trap followed by a filter. Take a look at the filters that come with breast pumps, they're designed to keep milk out of the pumps. In some ways your application is easier, because your sensor can be at a dead end, so air won't be flowing towards it.

Comment: Sanitary tri-clamp instruments for food/pharma/biotech are readily available, though without a picture/sketch of the milk container makes things a bit unclear.
https://www.ashcroft.com/products/pressure/pressure-gauges/1032-sanitary-pressure-gauge